# SQL Azure Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, azure-sql-database, deprecated

I am moving my database to SQL Azure.

I have simple procedure which worked fine in SQL Server 2012. But in Azure it does not work.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_getSizes](
    @ID_Bene int, 
    @strTaglie nvarchar(255) output)
AS
    declare @CodeTaglia nvarchar(10)

    set @strTaglie = ''

    Declare rs cursor for 
       SELECT Taglie.Codice 
       FROM Taglie 
       INNER JOIN Articoli ON Taglie.ID = Articoli.ID_Taglia 
       WHERE Articoli.ID_Bene = @ID_Bene

    open rs
    fetch next from rs into @CodeTaglia

    while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    begin
        set @strTaglie = @strTaglie + ',' + @CodeTaglia
        fetch next from rs into @CodeTaglia
    end
    close rs
    deallocate rs

    set @strTaglie = substring(@strTaglie, 3, len(@strTaglie))
```

When I execute this procedure in AZURE I get this error

> Deprecated feature 'String literals as column aliases' is not supported in this version of SQL Server.

Any ideas why it is?

Thanks

Comment: Does this work: `[Taglie.Codice] FROM [Taglie] INNER JOIN [Articoli] ON [Taglie.ID] = [Articoli.ID_Taglia] WHERE [Articoli.ID_Bene] = @ID_Bene`?

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: used [] braces it is not solution, I have already checked (Not as you wrote because it is fully wrong)

Comment: Is this complete procedure code? I executed this on Azure and did not get any error.

Comment: Also, Start index for SUBSTRING should be 2. :)

Comment: What do you mean with  EXEC uted .

Did you create procedure first after execute that procedure with parameters.